# State container(like Redux) in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working in a big project which we develop a Dashboard that display the user lots of data in different ways, charts tables and more.

The user has the power to filter the data, add filter expressions, filter data from table and mutate it.

Sometimes i feel really like i need a state container that will manage all of this data because it really gets hard for me to debug a problem or adding a new feature.

I would like your advice about what state container to use with angularjs (1.4.8)?
And what are the best ways to implement it on a big written project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on similar kind of work on which you are working on. I made a dashboard, which shows a lot of data using different plots( `line, volcano, bar, heatmaps`) and there was a way to interact all of them and filtering data and all.

For that purpose, I used `angular-redux`. Its very nice as at each interaction you can get your complete state object. That is managable and makes debugging very easier.

For that I followed [angular-redux doc](https://github.com/angular-redux/ng-redux) to make its configuration. Also, there is one chrome extension [redux-devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en), which shows all of your actions and state after each action. That helps you to keep tract on your state model.

If you want more info on redux, there are some good doc, which you can read.

[redux-basics(1)](http://redux.js.org/) [redux-basics(2)](http://redux.js.org/)

By looking at your need, I would recommend you to use redux.

Hopefully this will be helpful for u. If you need any other info, Let me know